# VLAN ID over DHCP for Management Interface of Fortinet FortiAP

Tags: dhcp, vlan, fortinet, fortigate, dhcp-option

When configuring the FortiAP device it's desirable to configure the VLAN ID for the tagged management network. Accordingly to the manual it's possible to do so by "telnetting" to the FortiAP device and setting the variable AP_MGMT_VLAN_ID by hand.

Since the FortiAP device can receive some informations over DHCP options, like the CAPWAP as described on the manual, I would like to know which DHCP option should be passed to the device to set the VLAN ID of the management interface without connecting to the device via CLI.

We're running the `isc-dhcp-server` and the CAPWAP Option 138 is working perfectly. But we are missing the VLAN ID feature. Since the documentation does not provide information on this question, I'm looking for solutions on the Serverfault community.

**EDIT (Better explanation):**

The FortiAP unit have some options that can be configured via the CLI. I'm interested only on two of them.

The first one is working okay, which is the WiFi Controller IP addresses (the FortiGate unit). This value is fed by the DHCP server with the Option 138 containing the IP address of the FG unit, as described exactly on the manual.

The second one which I'm asking about is the AP_MGMT_VLAN_ID, that should be defined. But I don't want to set this manually on ***ALL*** the FortiAP units, I just want an automated mode to do this. I was thinking in using DHCP with some specific option, but I don't know if the FortiAP can handle this. The DHCP Option 132 is defined as the VLAN ID option, but setting this was a no go for the FortiAP unit.

I've already contacted Fortinet, but they are still trying to "schedule a meeting" just to answer this question.

Comment: Are you asking if there is such a DHCP option for the access points, or are you asking what the option code is? Have you tried contacting the vendor?

Comment: Yes, I'm in contact with the vendor, but they are too slow. There's the default Option 132 for the VLAN ID, but this doest not appears to be working. I'll update the question with this information.